# Let $\{a_n\} ,\{b_n\}$ be given bounded sequences of positive real numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\} ,\{b_n\}$ be given bounded sequences of positive real numbers. Then (Here $ a_n\uparrow a$ means $a_n$ increase to a n goes to $\infty$, similarly, $b_n\downarrow b$ means $b_n$ decreases to b as n goes to $\infty$)

A. If $ a_n\uparrow a$, then $sup_{n\geq1}\; (a_nb_n)\leq a(sup_{n\geq1}\;b_n)$

B. If $ b_n\downarrow b$, then $inf_{n\geq1}\;(a_nb_n)\geq(inf_{n\geq1}\;a_n)b$

Comment: That doesn't seem right... Are you certain that it should be $=$ and not $\leq$ or $\geq$? For instance, in A, if the sequence $a_n$ goes $1,2,20,20,20,\ldots$, and $b_n$ goes $40,20,1,1,1,\ldots$. Or maybe you mean $\liminf $ and $\limsup$?

Comment: @Arthur .. this problem asked in CSIR exam ...and i typed every thing is right

Comment: Just because it's asked in an exam does not mean that it is right!!!

Comment: If $ a_n\uparrow a$, then $sup_{n\geq1}\; (a_nb_n)<a(sup_{n\geq1}\;b_n)$

Comment: If $ b_n\downarrow b$, then $inf_{n\geq1}\;(a_nb_n)>(inf_{n\geq1}\;a_n)b$

Comment: @Arthur and user21820 ...what about these conditions

Comment: If you use $\leq$ and $\geq$ instead of $<$ and $>$, then it looks good.

Comment: @Arthur...you mean if the above two conditions true when i use $\leq$ and $\geq$ instead of < and >,

Answer (score 2):

For a counter-example to A, let $a_1=0$ and $a_n=1-2^{-n}$ for $n>1$, let $b_1=2$ and $b_n=0$ for $n>1$. Then  $a=1$ so $a\sup_nb_n=\sup_nb_n=2$ while $\sup_na_nb_n=0$. Counters to B are similar .

Answer (score -1):

A.
Since $a_n$ increases to $a$, $a_n\leq a$ for all $n$
Also by definition, $b_n\leq sup (b_n)$. Therefore by using the product rule for inequalities $a_nb_n\leq a(sup(b_n)) \forall n$. The answer follows from this result.

B can be answered similarly to how how A is answered